# progress bar in public google drive upload

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I have a code that allows my website users to upload to a central Google Drive account.  So far it works great, I am simply trying to add in a progress bar.

Here, is the form HTML I have, I have been able to add a progress bar, it just does not move from 0%.

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS File Upload</title>
    <style>
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .progress_outer {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .progress {
        width: 20%;
        background: #DEDEDE;
        height: 20px;  
    }
    </style>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Besides that, I did some more research and have found a template example, I am just not sure how to implement it correctly into my existing code. Here is what I found from Caja Playground.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 37
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div id="progressbar"></div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Default determinate progress bar.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, You only put the html file , where is the gs file ? also Its not possible unless you use chunk to upload ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use external libraries like MediaUploader js file. See the following tutorial. It includes every functions such as Create folder, upload file, view images, view content image text, show share files only etc.

[Demo of using Google Drive API](https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript)